# Issue with System.Array.FindAll ()

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Did vb6 years ago. Trying to upgrade brain to VB.NET

```
Private Sub BtnFindAll_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnFindAll.Click

    Dim AutosArray() As String = {"Chrysler", "Corvette", "Lincoln", "Buick", "Ford", "Fiat", "Chevrolet", "Mercury"}
    Dim BooBee() As String

    ' The below line gets the error...
    BooBee = System.Array.FindAll(AutosArray, AddressOf MatchFunction)

    ' The below line gets the same error...
    'Dim BooBee() As String = Array.FindAll(AutosArray, AddressOf MatchFunction)

End Sub

Private Function MatchFunction(ByVal strAuto As String) As String
    If strAuto.IndexOf("c") > 1 Then
        Return strAuto
    End If
End Function
```

When I click on BtnFindAll I get the below error message:

> Exception Unhandled System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from
>   string "" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.'
>
> Inner Exception FormatException: Input string was not in a correct
>   format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MatchFunction should return a boolean to be compatible with the FindAll method

Something like this

```
Private Function MatchFunction(ByVal strAuto As String) As Boolean
    If strAuto.IndexOf("c") > 1 Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

You can read this point in the [Remarks section of the FindAll documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.findall?view=netframework-4.8#remarks)

Consider also that now there is another option to extract that information with a single line using Linq

```
BooBee = AutosArray.Where(Function(x) x.IndexOf("c") > 1).ToArray()
```